# Display fields compared of a value

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a number (size) field that can range from 0 to 7. I also have an intensity object that has 2 fields (in and out) I would like to display the number of objects in relation to the number in the number +1 field
What method can I use to solve my problem ?

I made a JSFiddle if someone have a solution for me .
https://jsfiddle.net/sebastianczech/2wfapuv4/61/

I also need, when I check the 'In = Out' checkbox, to attribute to 'Out' the same value than 'In'.

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="app">
<v-app >
<h1>Selection</h1>
<div v-for="car in cars">
  <v-select
    label="Selection"
    :items="car.version"
    item-text="color"
  >
  </v-select>
  <v-text-field
  label="Size"
  type="number"
  min="1"
  max="8"
  v-model="sizeValue">

  </v-text-field>
              <div v-for="(int, index) in intensity">
                <v-text-field
                        label="In"
                        type="number"
                          min="1"
                          max="100"
                        v-model="int.in">
                </v-text-field>
                <v-text-field
                        label="Out"
                        type="number"
                        min="1"
                         max="100"
                        v-model="int.out">
                </v-text-field>
            </div>
</div>
<v-checkbox label="Apply to All" v-model="checkboxAll"></v-checkbox>
<v-checkbox label="In = Out" v-model="checkboxInOut"></v-checkbox>
</v-app>
</div>
```

```
Vue.use(Vuetify);

var vm = new Vue({

  data() {
    return {
    checkboxInOut: false,
    checkboxAll: false,
    sizeValue: null,
    intensity:[
          {in: void 0, out:void 0}],
    cars: [
          {
          name: 'McQueen',
          version: [
          {color: 'blue' },                      
          {color: 'red' },
          {color: 'green' },
          {color: 'purple' },
          ]
         }
       ],
    }
  },
  methods: {

  }
})
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you explain with example..??

Comment: Not very clear, I can help, ping me on skype: syed_haroon

Comment: I have a number field that can range from 0 to 7. I also have an intensity object that has 2 fields (in and out) I would like to display the number of objects in relation to the number in the number +1 field

Comment: For example il the field whit number display 2, I need to display 3 intensity object( 2+ 1)

Comment: @chans, Can you help me ?

Comment: Yes, I can help, share your skype id

Comment: I don't have skype

Comment: share your gmail id, we can solve your issue over hangouts

Comment: I'm in job , I can talk here, just chatting

Comment: Okie, i wanna see the complete issue what your facing, if possible try to elobrate in question with an full examle, what you wanna achieve, that would really help to solve your issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201547/discussion-between-chans-and-sebastian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added fixes to the above code

working codepen here: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/KKKvrom?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <h1>Selection</h1>
<div v-for="car in cars">
  <v-select
    label="Selection"
    :items="car.version"
    item-text="color"
  >
  </v-select>
  <v-btn @click="addIntensity">
    add intensity
  </v-btn>
  <br>
  <br>

  </v-text-field>
  <div v-for="(int, index) in intensity">
    index{{index}}
    <v-btn @click="delIntensity(index)">
    delete intensity
  </v-btn>
    <v-text-field
                  label="In"
                  type="number"
                  min="1"
                  max="100"
                  v-model="int.in">
    </v-text-field>
    <v-text-field
                  label="Out"
                  type="number"
                  min="1"
                  max="100"
                  v-model="int.out">
    </v-text-field>
  </div>
</div>
        <v-checkbox label="Apply to All" v-model="checkboxAll"></v-checkbox>
        <v-checkbox label="In = Out" v-model="checkboxInOut"></v-checkbox>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    checkboxInOut: false,
    checkboxAll: false,
    sizeValue: 0,
    intensity:[
          {in: 0, out: 0}],
    cars: [
          {
          name: 'McQueen',
          version: [
          {color: 'blue' },                      
          {color: 'red' },
          {color: 'green' },
          {color: 'purple' },
          ]
         }
       ],
  }),
  methods: {
    addIntensity() {
      this.$set(this.intensity, this.intensity.length, {in: 0, out: 0});
    },
    delIntensity(index) {
      this.intensity.splice(index, 1);
    }
  },
  created() {
    for(var i = 0; i <= val;i++){
      this.$set(this.intensity, i, {in: 0, out: 0});
    }
  },
  watch: {
    checkboxInOut(val) {
      if (val) {
        this.intensity.forEach(x => {
          x.out  = x.in;
        });
      }
    }
  }
})
```